# How do I query multiple fields, pulling out those that are empty

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

First thing is I am a beginer so any advice please keep it simple with step by step instructions. I am using Access 2010.  I have a database that has multiple fields. Twenty of them are check boxes - 10 boxes for unsafe and 10 boxes for safe conditions. How do I query all the unsafe fields that are checked. Remember out of the 10 unsafe conditions 1 to 10 of the boxes (field) can be checked.

```
      Field1       Feild2           Feild3         Feild4         Feild5        Field6
```

Example:  Run - Safe() Run - UnSafe(X)  Walk - Safe()  Walk-UnSafe() Swim - Safe()  Swim - UnSafe(X)

Six fields, two of the three unsafe fields are selected, how do I write the query to pull out all Unsafe fields that are checked.  I've read about WHERE and or but can't get it correct.

So what I am trying to do is retrieve any record with an unsafe condition checked. How do I write the expression and where do I put it? Please enlighten me

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please post the code you have tried, and explain what happened when you tried it.

Comment: Also, edit your question to provide sample data and the results that you want.